# ERROR in node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/browser_adapter.d.ts

Tags: angular, runtime-error, angular6

I am getting this error and don't know the exact reason for this error

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/browser_adapter.d.ts(62,5): 

error TS2416: Property 'createScriptTag' in type 'BrowserDomAdapter' 
is not assignable to the same property in base type 'GenericBrowserDomAdapter'.

Type '(attrName: string, attrValue: string, doc?: Document) => 
HTMLScriptElement' is not assignable to type 
'(attrName: string, attrValue: string, doc?: any) => HTMLInputElement'.

Type 'HTMLScriptElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.
Property 'accept' is missing in type 'HTMLScriptElement'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by removing `node_modules` folder directly from the directory completely. Don't try to delete this folder within the `VS Code` because it didn't remove the folder completely.